# Positivity assumption in causal inference with continuous covariates

Tags: causality, treatment-effect

In causal inference, studies usually require several assumptions (e.g., Unconfoundedness) to make valid causal statements. One of these assumptions is the 'Positivity' Assumption (sometimes referred to as 'Common Support' / 'Overlap'). With measured covariates L, this assumption can be defined as:

> "the probability of receiving every value of treatment conditional on L is
> greater than zero, i.e., positive"
> [Hernán MA, Robins JM (2020). Causal Inference: What If.]

Consider a binary treatment **T**. My understanding is that by conditioning on L we get several subsets. Inside these subsets we need to have data for both treatment values (**T=1 and T=0**). I.e.   for each subset we need to have data for both treatment values (**T=1 and T=0**) with **all of the covariates having the exact same values**. This seems highly unlikely to me in settings with multiple continuous covariates (especially if we have additionally only few data).

**My questions are:**

1. Do I understand 'Positivity' correctly or have I misunderstood something?
2. How likely is this assumption to hold in settings with multiple continuous covariates?
3. Assuming Positivity is violated, to continue our analysis we would need to take an approach  (e.g. trimming) to adjust for the violation? (i.e. to ensure Positivity holds in our 'adjusted' data set)

Comment: A great paper on positivity just came out that address this exactly: https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.05010v1